# What is a intuitive meaning of linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

What is a intuitive meaning of linear transformation. Can you give any example which is a nonlinear transformation.

Comment: $f(ca+cb) = cf(a) + cf(b)$

Comment: @saldukoo I don't think you give an answer to a question asking for "intuition"